# How to allow for HTML rendering in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` in which I am showing a certain object from an array (in this case, an email message body). I am doing this with the following code:

```
NSString *string = [messages objectAtIndex:count-row-1];
NSString *string2 = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"];


[self.webView loadHTMLString:string2 baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

The problem with this code, the current one I am using, is that when the message body has some rich text or a lot of HTML images, formatting, etc., it does not display the message properly.

When I say 'it does not display to the message properly', I mean that all the above formatting is ignored, and just plain text from the image is pulled and shown.

Here is how I am loading the message body into the `messages` array:

```
for (CTCoreMessage *msg in messageSet) {
                [messages addObject:[msg bodyPreferringPlainText:&isHTML]];
```

`isHTML` is a `BOOL` set to `NO`, I don't know if this might be a problem?

I have now tried setting the `isHTML` `BOOL` to `YES`, and well, it fixed half of the problem. Now, some (most) formatting is shown (CSS/images/rich text), but unfortunately in the middle of some messages, I get tags like this, in the middle of no where:

```
style="margin-bottom: 15px; width: 570px; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not display the message properly?"

Comment: I tried to post an image, but didn't have enough reputation. Basically, it ignores all the formatting/images/CSS and just displays the text in the message.

Comment: What's in `messages`? Plain text? HTML? Post some example code from a message that doesn't work!

Comment: I have tried setting the BOOL to YES, please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [`htmlBody`](http://libmailcore.com/api/Classes/CTCoreMessage.html#//api/name/htmlBody) method on `CTCoreMessage` instead of `bodyPreferringPlainText:`, which prefers plain text when possible. You'll never see formatting if you deliberately pull the plain text version of the message body.

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't bodyPreferringPlainText: return the same if it was set to YES?

Comment: No. Read [the method documentation](http://libmailcore.com/api/Classes/CTCoreMessage.html#//api/name/bodyPreferringPlainText:) and also about "output parameters".

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now. So instead of adding the bodyPreferringPlainText to the array, add the msg.htmlBody to the array. Is this correct?